# Bash: switch from integer to float

Tags: bash, sed, floating-point, integer

I am iterating over a range of numbers but would like to switch from an integer to a floating point number with one decimal place (e.g. from 5 to 5.0) as illustrated by the loop below.

```
for coul in 5 6 7; do

    mkdir cc_${coul}                                      # <-- here, ${coul} 
                                                          # should be an integer

    ... some code ... 

    sed -i '15s/.*/variable coul equal '${coul}'/' cc.in  # <-- here, ${coul}
                                                          # must be a decimal 
                                                          # (e.g. 5.0)
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
"${coul}.0"
```

The braces are unnecessary in a Posix shell or in bash because `.` is not a valid identifier character, but they might be necessary in other shells. They certainly don't hurt.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. In the end I used:

`'...equal '${coul}'.0/' cc.in`

which I guess is the same thing.

Comment: @d-man: in this case, yes, but in general you should always quote variable expansions. There is no need for the single quotes in this command; you could simply double-quote the entire sed argument. But it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable; as far as `bash` is concerned, these are just strings that could be treated as numbers in the right context.

```
coul_f=$coul.0
sed -i '15s/.*/variable coul equal '"$coul_f"'/' cc.in
```